# Redux toolkit updating state on api response

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am fairly new to redux and reduxjs/toolkit and I'm stuck on updating the state after a successful api call.  I'm following along with the docs here -> https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { loginUser } from './actions';

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: { id: 0, name: '', email: '' },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      // trying to overwrite the state directly like this doesn't work
      state = { ...action.payload }
      // updating each individual part of the state object does work, but this is not ideal for scalability
      // state.id = action.payload.id;
      // state.name = action.payload.name;
      // state.email = action.payload.email;
    });
  },
```

As indicated in the comments, attempting to overwrite the entire state object does not work.  No error messages, but nothing happens.  However, updating each individual part of the state object does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux Toolkit is built on top of Immer. Immer lets you update the state in two ways.

Important: be careful you choose one or the other, never both.

#### 1. Mutate state

```js
builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.id = action.payload.id;
  state.name = action.payload.name;
  state.email = action.payload.email;
  // NEVER use return when mutating state
});
```

#### 2. Return new state

```js
builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  // NEVER mutate state when using return
  return {
    id: action.payload.id,
    name: action.payload.name,
    email: action.payload.email,
  };
});
```

The return syntax could simplify to the following:

```js
builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => action.payload);
```

But I do not recommend it. I think you're better off being explicit about the state changes in your reducers. It makes it easier to understand what changes are taking place.